# How to dynamically position two buttons on screen when item clicked in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a RecyclerView that is filled with items. What I want to achieve is that when I do a long click two FloatingActionButtons appear just above or underneath the item that I tapped on. I have everything implemented (Activity, RecyclerView, OnLongClickListener, etc) it is just the thing about how I can get two buttons dynamically positioned on the screen just above the item I clicked. When I click the item in the top area of the screen it should appear underneath the item, while it should appear over the item if I click an item in the downer part of the screen. The idea is like opening options, like a context menu, when doing a long click on the item.
I think code is not necessary for that. If you need it I will provide it. If you can give me a hint I am happy.

Thanks

Comment: By reading your question all you need is popup box  on the item clicked. right ?

Comment: Yes kind of, I would like instead of a popup box two FloatingActionButtons that appear, I think this is more beautiful @Sush

Comment: i would suggest use popup window with anchor to item clicked. Give transparent bg to popup window. it will help you handling ui clutter also